# First Responder Resigns When Editing a Constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to resize a height constraint when a user taps a UITextField.  The idea is basically to expand a sub-view which contains two UITextFields when the user taps one of the fields (my intention is to display a table in the expanded area).  The subview properly expands but the problem I'm having is that either text field immediately resigns as first responder when I change the constraint value and textFieldDidEndEditing executes right away.  Is there some way I can edit a constraint without resigning responder status?

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (self.routeSelectionVC && (textField == self.routeSelectionVC.fromTextField || textField == self.routeSelectionVC.toTextField)) {
        self.headerBarViewHeightConstraint.constant = 288;
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (self.routeSelectionVC && (textField == self.routeSelectionVC.fromTextField || textField == self.routeSelectionVC.toTextField)) {
        self.headerBarViewHeightConstraint.constant = 88;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when You explicitly call: `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` after changing constraint?

Comment: I ran similar code to yours, and I don't see the text field losing first responder status. Is soothing else getting the first responder status?